# What is known about the prime factorization of numbers of the form $2^k+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $n=2^k+1$, $k$ a positive integer. What is known about the prime factorization of these numbers?  For example, consider $J(n)=\Omega(n)-\omega(n)$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the sum of multiplicities in the prime factorization of $n$, and $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. It would seem that $J(2^{3^i}+1)=i$ for $i$ a positive integer.  Is $J(2^k+1)<J(2^{3^i})$ when $k<3^i$?  Unfortunately, for these numbers we do not have Fermat's little theorem and the resulting arsenal of theorems and propositions that can be derived from it. Hence my question, is there anything we know about the prime factorization of these numbers that might help settle questions like the one above?

Comment: This seems like a spectacularly hard problem. In particular, we don't even know how many Fermat Primes there are.

Comment: See [factorization of Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Factorization_of_Fermat_numbers) and its links.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the interest on that page seems focused on Fermat numbers, those of the form $2^{2^i}+1$, so that numbers for which $2^i<k<2^{i+1}$ are missed.  But I will look carefully at the references.

Comment: I think this question is quite broad. For example image $k=q_1\cdot q_2$, where both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are **odd**. Then from 
$$2^{q_1} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{q_1}+1} \Rightarrow 2^{k} \equiv (-1)^{q_2} \pmod{2^{q_1}+1} \Rightarrow \\
2^{k} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{q_1}+1}$$
In this case, $k=3^i$ and $q_1=3^j$, $q_2=3^t$ such that $i=j+t$.

Comment: Googling the cunningham project page should be helpful. The site also explains the algebraic factors that such numbers have.